# pandas plot multiple df in canvas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, tkinter

I have difficulty with setting two different data plots inside one axis in tkinter canvas. Currently is being displayed only last plot, second is hidden.

**Update**:
Test example is working, but not in my original setup.
Problem is moved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59577455/pandas-squished-plot-on-one-axis).

Test example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

window = Tk()
window.geometry('800x600')

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
df['y'] = np.random.randint(1, 10, 10)

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['x'] = np.linspace(1, 10, 50)
df2['y'] = np.random.randint(1, 10, 50)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x='x', y='y', kind='bar', ax=ax, width=1., figsize=(3, 2.5), legend=None)
df2.plot(x='x', y='y', kind='line', ax=ax, legend=None)

Canvas(window, background='white')  # create canvas field
canvas_plot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, window)  # Draw area
canvas_plot.get_tk_widget().grid(column=1, row=6, padx=1, pady=10, rowspan=2, columnspan=3)
canvas_plot.draw()  # draw canvas

window.mainloop()
```

**Question:**

How to make this plots to be displayed in one figure?