# Pandas squished plot on one axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two data frames with i need to plot in one axis. Unfortunately one of displayed data and xticks are shifted to the left.

**Test example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.linspace(20, 30, 10)
df['y'] = np.random.randint(1, 10, 10)

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['x'] = np.linspace(1, 40, 50)
df2['y'] = np.random.randint(1, 10, 50)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x='x', y='y', kind='bar', ax=ax, width=1., figsize=(3, 2.5), legend=None)
df2.plot(x='x', y='y', kind='line', ax=ax, legend=None, color='red')

plt.show()
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Question:**
How to proper display this data on one axis?

Comment: it looks like it's just an issue with the axis formatting, take a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810009/matplotlib-plot-bar-and-line-charts-together

Answer (score 3):

I was only able to solve this by doing the plot in matplotlib directly:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.linspace(20, 30, 10)
df['y'] = np.random.randint(1, 10, 10)

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['x'] = np.linspace(1, 40, 50)
df2['y'] = np.random.randint(1, 10, 50)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(x=df.x, height=df.y)
ax.plot(df2.set_index('x'), c='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Pandas bar plots are categorical (They always go from 0 to N-1), while matplotlib bar plots are numeric. Hence it's not a bug, but a different way of bar plot interpretation.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest OK, thanks for the explanation (and for all of your other amazing work on this site)!