# Plotting superimposed charts (line and bar) with pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am testing the capabilities of pandas to plot financial data (price and volume) on the same chart. If I try to render both data as lines, it works fine:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

a = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-06-01',freq = 'D')
b = np.random.normal(size = len(a), loc = 50)
v = np.random.normal(size = len(a), loc = 1000)
c = pd.DataFrame(index = a, data = zip(b,v), columns = ['price', 'volume'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,8))
bx = ax.twinx()
c.price.plot.line(ax = ax, color = 'r')
c.volume.plot.line(ax = bx,  color = 'g', alpha = .2)
plt.show()
```

This gives:
[image]

However if I try to render one as a line and the other as a bar chart, by replacing the 3 last lines by:

```
c.price.plot.line(ax = ax, color = 'r')
c.volume.plot.bar(ax = bx,  color = 'g', alpha = .2)
plt.show()
```

This gives the wrong result:
[image]

Would anybody know how to make the above code work with line + bar  ??

Comment: This is a pretty common question, the last version of it appeared only [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59577455/pandas-squished-plot-on-one-axis). In short: Use matplotlib, not pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Matplotlib** plotting library.

Matplotlib's function [pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/pyplot_summary.html) has functions **bar** and **plot**. You can use them to display data on the same chart.

[Example](https://pythondata.com/visualizing-data-overlaying-charts/)